# transfer function of RC in parallel

Tags: impedance, parallel, transfer-function

I was looking at [RC in parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit) (at the bottom of the page at the link) to understand the transfer function \$\frac{V_{out}}{I_{in}}  = \frac{R}{1+SRC}\$, in the case that the input is a constant current.

Given that the nodes of the input and output are shared, \$V_{out} = V_{in}\$, I came to the conclusion that the transfer function is equal to \$\frac{|V_{out}|}{|I_{in}|}  = \frac{|V_{in}|}{|I_{in}|}\$. Then, from Ohm's law, I decided that the transfer function is just equal to the absolute value of the total  impedance.

As far as I know, the total impedance is \$ \frac{1}{Z_{tot}} = \frac{1}{R} + i\omega C \$. Hence, \$Z_{tot} = \frac{R}{1+i\omega CR}  \$ and \$  |Z_{tot}| = \frac{R \sqrt{(1+ \omega^2 C^2 R^2)}}{1 + \omega^2 C^2 R^2}\$, instead of what they have on the wikipedia page, which is \$\frac{R}{1+\omega RC} \$.

Did I miss something?

[image]

Comment: If I can see good on Wiki is: R/(1+sRC) which is the same as yours.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič  Sorry, I think my answer is \$ \frac{R}{\sqrt{1+ \omega^2 C^2 R^2}} \$

Comment: I don't get it. There is a formula in complex plane and you calculated the absolute value of the complex number. What you have is a magnitude, so where is the comparison between yours and Wiki's? What would you like to acheive?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Is 'S' in the wikipedia's formula the same as \$ i \omega\$ ?

Comment: Yep, the s operator is the Laplace operator, actually s=iw

Comment: @MarkoBuršič My apologies, I should've thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: @Blackwidow Actually, \$s=\sigma+j\,\omega\$. When just interested in the frequency part, then \$\sigma=0\$ and \$s=j\,\omega\$.

Comment: @Blackwidow Electrical engineers use \$j\$ so that you don't confuse us with \$i\$ being an imaginary number. I'll let you figure out why we don't use \$i\$.

Comment: @KingDuken The reasoning behind j vs i is *much* deeper than many imagine. At least back to quaternions: [Sir William R. Hamilton to John T. Graves, Esq](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/QLetter/QLetter.pdf) and [Euler to Goldbach](http://eulerarchive.maa.org//correspondence/letters/OO0841.pdf). Also see [Geometric Algebra](http://www.faculty.luther.edu/~macdonal/) and [Clifford Algebra](https://slehar.wordpress.com/2014/03/18/clifford-algebra-a-visual-introduction/), too. Considering outer products of bivectors is sufficient to get some points. There's depth here.